# What subsets of a covering space cover their image?

Tags: covering-spaces, group-actions

Say I have a covering map $p \colon E \to B$. Then for which subsets $F$ of $E$, is $p|_F \colon F \to p(F)$ a covering map?

If it makes things easier, assume $E$ is simply connected, that is, the universal cover of $B$.

I was looking at the group of deck transformations (I don't know if they make sense in the most general settings) and it seems that sets of orbits under a fixed subgroup work. We should also be able to take union of such things, but I'm not sure under what conditions.

Comment: I don't know if the (group-actions) tag is appropriate, feel free to retag.

Comment: The set of orbits of what?  Consider the canonical $\mathbb R\to S^1$. What are you envisioning when you take the subgroup $2\mathbb Z$ of $\mathbb Z$ - what subset of $\mathbb R$ are you envisioning?

Comment: Take any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and take the union of orbits of points in $A$ under $2 \mathbb{Z}$. This works as an $F$, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, those will be covers, although there are lots of covers that are not of that sort. For example, $\cup (p,p+1)$ where the union is taken over all primes $p$ is still a (trivial) cover of its image.

Comment: Hmm. I originally thought that the complicated examples could be taken care of by some sort of union, but your example makes that unlikely. Maybe there is no nice characterization involving the group action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any component of a preimage of a subset $A$ of $B$ is a cover of $A$, I believe (at least for open subsets). Taking the preimage of small subsets just gives you one copy of the small subset for each group element, and taking larger subsets gives you more interesting covering spaces. In fact, two preimages 'merge together' exactly when the original set contains a non-trivial loop.

For instance, a simply connected subset of the torus lifts to infinitely many disjoint copies of itself, but a big patch that loops around a meridian and touches itself lifts to disjoint copies of an 'unwinding' of itself, an infinite set that is homotopic to a line.

One problem with taking preimages of non-open subsets is that the open subset of $B$ corresponding to small neighborhoods in the non-open subset under the subspace topology may not be well-covered.

Comment: Yes, preimages work, but even smaller things might work. That's why I have orbits under subgroups. And the union I'm worried about is for orbits of different subgroups.

Comment: I think you need to choose components of preimages, and that nothing smaller works.

Comment: Yes, $F$ is can be any clopen subset of a pre-image, I believe - a clopen subset being essentially a union of connected components of the pre-image.

Comment: The disjoint union of any covering spaces is a covering space. If your two covering spaces are not disjoint, I believe you still have a covering space if the two are open, but not in general. For instance, the integers cover a point on the circle, and (0,1) covers the rest of the circle, but their union is not a cover.